# How is type (index 2) under getimagesize() method different from image types?

Tags: php, image

```
getimagesize($_FILES['user_profile_photo']['tmp_name']);
```

Above function [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) gives the following result

```
Array ( [0] => 1024 [1] => 1012 [2] => 3 [3] => width="1024" height="1012" [bits] => 8 [mime] => image/png )
```

Where Index 2 value is "3" , How different is this from imagetypes defined in the below link.

> Returns a bit-field corresponding to the image formats supported by
>   the version of GD linked into PHP. The following bits are returned,
>   IMG_BMP | IMG_GIF | IMG_JPG | IMG_PNG | IMG_WBMP | IMG_XPM | IMG_WEBP.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagetypes.php

Comment: What do you mean, _“How different is this from”_? These are defined constants with integer values, that each have a single specific bit set. If you want to know what the corresponding integer numbers are, you can simply dump the constants: `var_dump(IMG_BMP, IMG_GIF, IMG_JPG, IMG_PNG);`

Comment: okay so the integer numbers defined by IMG_BMP , IMG_GIF etc are same as that in index 2 , is that right ? @misorude